# How to update listview after changing data in JSON?

Tags: android, json

Hello everyone and happy new year

I have JSON class where I retrieve some data that are retrieve from a database. The format of this JSON file is

```
{"people":[{"id":"15","first_name":"Theo","last_name":"Tziomakas","bio":"Hello from 
Theo!!!","created":"2015-01-11 21:48:51"},
{"id":"16","first_name":"Jim","last_name":"Chytas","bio":"Hello from Chytas","created":"2015-01-11 
21:53:42"}]}.
```

The idea is to retrieve the "first_name" and "second_name" in a listview. The "bio" should appear in another activity,but I don't know how to do that:(.

Here is my code.

```
 public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
 ListView list;
 TextView fname;
TextView lname;


 ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> oslist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
//URL to get JSON Array
private static String url = "http://xxxxxxx/tutorials/index.php";
//JSON Node Names
private static final String TAG_OS = "people";
private static final String TAG_FIRST_NAME = "first_name";
private static final String TAG_SECOND_NAME = "last_name";
//private static final String TAG_BIO = "bio";
JSONArray android = null;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    oslist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();


            new JSONParse().execute();
        }


private class JSONParse extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        fname = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.first_name);
        lname = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.last_name);
        //abio = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.bio);

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Getting Data ...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }
    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
        // Getting JSON from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
        return json;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
        try {
            // Getting JSON Array from URL
            android = json.getJSONArray(TAG_OS);
            for(int i = 0; i < android.length(); i++){
                JSONObject c = android.getJSONObject(i);
                // Storing  JSON item in a Variable
                String first_name = c.getString(TAG_FIRST_NAME);
                String last_name = c.getString(TAG_SECOND_NAME);
                //String bio = c.getString(TAG_BIO);
                // Adding value HashMap key => value
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put(TAG_FIRST_NAME, first_name);
                map.put(TAG_SECOND_NAME, last_name);
                //map.put(TAG_BIO, bio);
                oslist.add(map);
                list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, oslist,
                        R.layout.list_v,
                        new String[] { TAG_FIRST_NAME,TAG_SECOND_NAME }, new int[] {
                        R.id.first_name,R.id.last_name});
                list.setAdapter(adapter);
                list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                            int position, long id) {
                        String bio = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.bio))
                                .getText().toString();
                        switch (position) {
                            case 0:

                            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SingleActivity.class);
                            i.putExtra("bio", bio);
                            startActivity(i);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
     }
  }
}
```

And finally I have the SecondActivity class,but nothing is shown when I click the first row of list.

```
 public class SingleActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
 TextView text;
 JSONArray android = null;
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_single);

    text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
    String bio = getIntent().getStringExtra("bio");

    try {
        JSONObject profileJSON = new JSONObject(bio);
        android = profileJSON.getJSONArray(bio);
        text.setText(""+android);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


  }
}
```

Thank you.

EDIT:The problem I had is fixed. Now I want to do something else. Let us suppose that we update the data in an existing row by changing "first_name,"last_name" and finally bio. It is done very easily in phpmyadmin tool. The problem is that the updated row is not shown in the listview. I have to reinstall the app in order to see it. Any ideas in that?

Comment: This code has no sens - you are setting new Adapter for each JSON array's element ... you need to take some basic tutorial on how listviews/adapters work on android ... fx: do not use `((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.bio))
                                .getText().toString()` rather use `HashMap<String, String> item = (HashMap<,>)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);`

Comment: also "bio" is not an json array but a simple string ...

Comment: Uncomment this code `map.put(TAG_BIO, bio);` This must have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this ,

replace onPostExecute with this

```
 protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
   pDialog.dismiss();
   try {
       list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
       // Getting JSON Array from URL
       android = json.getJSONArray(TAG_OS);
       for(int i = 0; i < android.length(); i++){
           JSONObject c = android.getJSONObject(i);
           // Storing  JSON item in a Variable
           String first_name = c.getString(TAG_FIRST_NAME);
           String last_name = c.getString(TAG_SECOND_NAME);
           //String bio = c.getString(TAG_BIO);
           // Adding value HashMap key => value
           HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
           map.put(TAG_FIRST_NAME, first_name);
           map.put(TAG_SECOND_NAME, last_name);
           map.put(TAG_BIO, bio);
           oslist.add(map);


       }

       ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, oslist,
               R.layout.list_v,
               new String[] { TAG_FIRST_NAME,TAG_SECOND_NAME }, new int[] {
               R.id.first_name,R.id.last_name});
       list.setAdapter(adapter);
       list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                   int position, long id) {
               String bio =oslist.get(position).get(TAG_BIO);
              // switch (position) {
                 //  case 0:

                   Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SingleActivity.class);
                   i.putExtra("bio", bio);
                   startActivity(i);
                   break;
               //}
           }
       });
   } catch (JSONException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

and SingleActivity

```
text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
String bio = getIntent().getStringExtra("bio");
text.setText(bio );
```

Comment: It works. Thank you my friend! I marked your answer as "correct"

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to what you put in the intent.

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                        int position, long id) {
                    String bio = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.bio))
                            .getText().toString();
                    switch (position) {
                        case 0:

                        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SingleActivity.class);
                        i.putExtra("bio", bio);
                        startActivity(i);
                        break;
                    }
                }
```

notice that you take the text from a text view and add it to and intent.

When you retreive it use it as if its a json object.
If you want the bio string, you could put that in a variable, and then send it to an intent with just the string.

for example

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, oslist,
                   R.layout.list_v,
                    new String[] { TAG_FIRST_NAME,TAG_SECOND_NAME }, new int[] {
                    R.id.first_name,R.id.last_name});
            list.setAdapter(adapter);
            String bio = c.getString("bio");
            list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                        int position, long id) {

                    switch (position) {
                        case 0:

                        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SingleActivity.class);
                        i.putExtra("bio", bio);
                        startActivity(i);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            });
```

when retrieving it its easier to just do it with

```
public class SingleActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    TextView text;
    JSONArray android = null;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_single);

        text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
        String bio = getIntent().getStringExtra("bio");

        text.settext(bio)


        }
    }
```

now there is prob some bugs in these example, since i have not java or android sdk installed on my computer

Comment: it will not even compile ... `bio`(in 2nd code snippet) should be final ... but then it will be always the last value from the array ...